# Error trying to get window of iFrame

Tags: javascript, angular

I am attempting to get the window of an iFrame using the following code:

```
  var frameWindow = document.getElementById("loginframe");
  var iWindow = frameWindow.contentWindow;
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting the following error:

```
Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.)
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, "contentWindow" is highlighted in red which is an error...

[image]

I have tried casting:

```
  let map = document.getElementById("loginframe") as HTMLObjectElement;
  let insideDoc = map.contentDocument;
```

But this does not work either...

Is this something to do with angular libraries that perhaps I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't select a DOM element like that you should use a viewChild to do that.

```
<iframe src="urlHere" #loginframe ></iframe>
```

Then you can use it in your TypeScript code like this:

```
@ViewChild('loginframe') loginframe: ElementRef;
```

After that you can select the element like this: (Note: you should cast it to a `HTMLIFrameElement`)

```
const win = (<HTMLIFrameElement> this.loginframe).nativeElement.contentWindow;
```

Here is a fully working plnkr! (open your console to see the output)

https://embed.plnkr.co/kicS6o8QlOEcXyMKNjFi/

Comment: Looks promising, however I get this error:  Type 'ElementRef' cannot be converted to type 'HTMLIFrameElement' (... what's strange is that if I force teh application to load a broken module, remove it, then re-load... it works. But then as soon as I try and build from scratch, it breaks again!)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, this has assisted me in solving the problem. I changed this line: (<HTMLIFrameElement> this.loginframe).nativeElement.contentWindow; to this line: this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow